# Check if a list is in a list of tuples

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a function where I have to match a tuple to a list of tuples and  return a bool if the two elements of my first tuple appear in any tuples of the later list. So far i have try to use `elem` (only works if my first list have the same number of element with the sublist) and `isInfixOf` (variable not in scope). Any hints to go about this?

```
matching ("Monday","Tuesday") [("Monday","Tuesday",10),("Tuesday","Sunday",20), ("Wednesday", "Friday", 22)] -> False
matching ("Monday","Tuesday") [("Tuesday","Monday",10),("Tuesday","Sunday",20), ("Wednesday", "Friday", 22)] -> False
```

Comment: You talk about matching a List to a List of a List but your examples are matching a Tuple to a List of Tuples (with differing Tuple length), i.e. `(String, String) -> [(String, String, Int)] -> Bool`.

Comment: @dave my bad, I do want to match a tuple with a list of tuples.

Comment: Both your examples indicate a `False` result; what would produce a `True` result?

Comment: For example: [("Tuesday","Friday",10),("Tuesday","Sunday",20), ("Wednesday", "Friday", 22)].
In other words, there can't be a tuple where the first two elements are Monday and Tuesday ( or Tuesday and Monday)

Comment: @K.U: can you update your question with when the function is meant to return `True` and when it is meant to return `False` because at the moment you say you have to "return a bool if" but you _always_ have to return a `Bool` the question is when.  Alternatively, if you can write a function that returns the correct result for one tuple then you can use my answer to make it work on a list trivially (and perhaps the others similarly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see what you want to do:

1. You have to match a tuple to a tuple of another length, returning `True` if they match or `False` otherwise.
2. Apply this to our list and return `True` if there are any matches and `False` if there aren't.

Are there any standard functions that help?
[Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle) is the resource to use to try and find functions that help.  Of course there's a learning curve in knowing what to search for.

I tried `(a -> b -> Bool) -> a -> [b] -> Bool` which is the type of your function where `a` is the Tuple you want to match and `b` is the Tuple in your list.  This didn't get any useful matches.  But then I tried `(b -> Bool) -> [b] -> Bool` results are [here](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28b+-%3E+Bool%29+-%3E+%5Bb%5D+-%3E+Bool), and the second match is a function called `any` (the first function is `all` which is useful but doesn't do what you want!).

Now all we need is a function that takes in the Tuple and returns true if they match.

Using your tuples I tried `(a,b) -> (a,b,c) -> Bool` and ... found no matches!  Looks like we are going to have to write that ourselves.

Something like this should work:
`compareTuples a b = fst a == fst b && snd a == snd b`
or `compareTuples (a,b) (c,d, _) = a == c && b == d`.

Hmm, this function has the type `(a -> b -> Bool)` but `any` takes `(b -> Bool)`, so how can we make that work?  By partial application of course!

`matching t xs = any (compareTuples t) xs`

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using a fold:

```
matching (p,q) lst = foldl (\acc (x,y,_) -> if (x == p) && (y==q) then True || acc else False || acc) False lst
```

Basically, do a pattern match of input against the tuples in the list. If at least one match is found, the accumulator will be set to True.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple if you use [lenses](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1):

```
matching a bs = not . any (\b -> (a^._1 == b^._1 && a^._2 == b^._2)
                              || (a^._1 == b^._2 && a^._2 == b^._1) ) $ bs
```

Which can be further simplified using eta reduction:

```
matching a = not . any (\b -> (a^._1 == b^._1 && a^._2 == b^._2)
                           || (a^._1 == b^._2 && a^._2 == b^._1) )
```